# Canvas Following cursor

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events

I want that firework follow Mouse/cursor, I have tired so much but cannot find solution.

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script>
/* Starter js1k Template Code */
var b = document.body;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var a = c.getContext('2d');
document.body.clientWidth;

/* js1k Entry Code - Color Shift */
function p(){this.x=~~(Math.random()*(e-e/3-e/3+1))+e/3,this.y=~~(Math.random()*(h-h/3-h/3+1))+h/3,this.a=.1,this.c=this.d=1,this.b=(e+h)/7}var e=h=c.width=c.height=250,f=c.style,g=[],j=0;k=this.requestAnimationFrame||this.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||this.mozRequestAnimationFrame||this.oRequestAnimationFrame||this.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(a){setTimeout(a,1e3/60)},b.style.backgroundColor="#000",f.position="absolute",f.left=f.top="50%",f.marginLeft=f.marginTop="-125px",function q(){k(q,c),a.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out",a.fillStyle="rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)",a.fillRect(0,0,e,h),a.globalCompositeOperation="lighter";var b=g.length;for(0==j%2&&g.push(new p);b--;){var d=g[b],f=b,i=(d.b-d.a)/d.b;d.c=.5+d.d*i,d.a+=d.c,d.alpha=2.5*i,a.beginPath(),a.arc(d.x,d.y,d.a,0,2*Math.PI),a.fillStyle="hsla("+(~~(Math.random()*(j+100-(j-100)+1))+(j-100))+", 100%, 1%, "+d.alpha+")",a.fill(),d.a>d.b&&g.splice(f,1)}j++}();  
</script>
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: @user1465639 What are you talking about?

Comment: @qasimali What user1465639 meant was you have a lot of code on 1 line, which means it's hard to read it. He asked you to format your code, i.e. make it readable so that we figure out what's not working with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the code - it will move the canvas element itself along with the mouse. You might have to adjust other CSS to avoid scrollbar (overflow: hidden):

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  c.style.left = e.clientX + "px"
  c.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
};
```

```js
/* Starter js1k Template Code */
var b = document.body;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var a = c.getContext('2d');

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  c.style.left = e.clientX + "px"
  c.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
};

/* js1k Entry Code - Color Shift */
function p(){this.x=~~(Math.random()*(e-e/3-e/3+1))+e/3,this.y=~~(Math.random()*(h-h/3-h/3+1))+h/3,this.a=.1,this.c=this.d=1,this.b=(e+h)/7}var e=h=c.width=c.height=250,f=c.style,g=[],j=0;k=this.requestAnimationFrame||this.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||this.mozRequestAnimationFrame||this.oRequestAnimationFrame||this.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(a){setTimeout(a,1e3/60)},b.style.backgroundColor="#000",f.position="absolute",f.left=f.top="50%",f.marginLeft=f.marginTop="-125px",function q(){k(q,c),a.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out",a.fillStyle="rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)",a.fillRect(0,0,e,h),a.globalCompositeOperation="lighter";var b=g.length;for(0==j%2&&g.push(new p);b--;){var d=g[b],f=b,i=(d.b-d.a)/d.b;d.c=.5+d.d*i,d.a+=d.c,d.alpha=2.5*i,a.beginPath(),a.arc(d.x,d.y,d.a,0,2*Math.PI),a.fillStyle="hsla("+(~~(Math.random()*(j+100-(j-100)+1))+(j-100))+", 100%, 1%, "+d.alpha+")",a.fill(),d.a>d.b&&g.splice(f,1)}j++}();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```